# jQuery Ajax in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-cloud-storage

I am practicing Ajax with GCS. So I upload two html files to the bucket. `bucket/aaa.html` is set `allUsers`. `bucket/test/bbb.html` set `allAuthenticatedUsers`. I want to load `bbb.html` in iframe of `aaa.html`.

Code in `aaa.thml`:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#aaa_iframe_id").attr('src', "/")
        $("#aaa_iframe_id").contents().find('html').html(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
});
```

`token` is generated by`firebase.app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`

Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code>
    <Message>Authentication required.</Message>
</Error>
```

What should I do?

**Update**

When `url` was `https:/storage.googleapis.com/bucket/test/bbb.html`, I got `Request URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/storage.googleapis.com/bucket/test/bbb.html`.
([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkCMk.png))

So, I change `url` to `./test/bbb.html`.([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZkwC.png))

I still got 401 after changed `url`

Comment: If it were me, I'd use a chrome browser an examine the traffic sent by the browser to GCP.  I'd look to see what (if any) credentials are being sent in the iframe request.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I update images. Please tell me if I upload the wrong information.

Comment: Could you please try the following documentation regarding auth in Google Cloud Storage and let me know if the error changes? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth

Comment: `<oauth2_token>` mentioned in the https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#apiauth equal to the token obtained by https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients?

Comment: If they are the same, Does this code `beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)}` match the phrase "include your application's access token in the Authorization header in every request that requires authentication." ?

Comment: It looks like you are using Firebase cloud storage and this service gets stored in Google Cloud Storage for Google Cloud Platform and the access control options for Cloud Storage buckets (GCP) are different than the security rules for Firebase. For more information please read https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#apis. 
In order to authenticate your request for Cloud Storage you can use the JSON API https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing. Please let me know if the error changes.